# how to save my output in two separate columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have an output which contains scores and the word with topic number, how can i save it in dataframe with 3 different columns? a: topic name, b : words, c : scores?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific dict you could use something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    -1: [('gun', 0.03), ('shut', 0.2)], 
    0: [('http', 0.08), ('wireless', 0.1)],
}

data = defaultdict(list)
for key in d:
    data["topic_name"] += [key] * len(d[key]) 
    data["words"] += [i[0] for i in d[key]]
    data["scores"] += [i[1] for i in d[key]]
    
pd.DataFrame(data)

-------------------------------------------------------

    topic_name  words      scores
0   -1          gun         0.03
1   -1          shut        0.20
2    0          http        0.08
3    0          wireless    0.10
-------------------------------------------------------
```

For a nested dict, you could use something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    -1: {
        'gun':0.1,
        'people': 0.2,
        'chut': 0.3
    },
    0: {
        'http': 0.03,
        'tco': 0.06,
        'wireless': 0.8
    }
}

data = defaultdict(list)
for key in d:
    data["topic_name"] += [key] * len(d[key]) 
    data["words"] += list(d[key].keys())
    data["scores"] += list(d[key].values())
    
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This results to the following data frame:

```py
    topic_name  words   scores
0   -1          gun       0.10
1   -1          people    0.20
2   -1          chut      0.30
3   0           http      0.03
4   0           tco       0.06
5   0           wireless  0.80
```